# <f:setPropertyActionListener it does not work with Dialog

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

The selected item is not displayed in the dialog box when you click the edit button

en el  apartado del dialog tengo el rendered, que se supone realiza la llamada al controllador

this is my Carrucel.Xhtml

```
           <p:commandButton update="tab:formIndex:myform:editarSlider"  oncomplete="PF('popupEditSlider').show()" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar">
             <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{carrucelController.selectCarrucel}" />
           </p:commandButton>                            


<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Editar Slider" widgetVar="popupEditSlider" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                <p:outputPanel id="editarSlider" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty carrucelController.selectCarrucel}" columnClasses="label,value">                            
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <img src="#{arrucelController.selectCarrucel.imagen}" style="height: 80px;"/>
                        </f:facet>

                        <h:outputText value="Titulo" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{arrucelController.selectCarrucel.nombre}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Texto:" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{arrucelController.selectCarrucel.textoImagen}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <br></br>
                    <p:commandButton id="btnGuardar" styleClass="clsButton" value="Guardar" actionListener="#{carrucelController.editSlider}"
                    oncomplete="PF('popupEditSlider').hide()" update="@form"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
```

My Controller

here I have defined the method for the edition

```
public void editSlider() {
    log.info("[-- Editar Slider:  " + selectCarrucel.getNombre() + " --]");

    for(int i=0; i<lstCarrucel.size(); i++) {
        log.info("[-- " + selectCarrucel.getNombre() + " - " + 
        selectCarrucel.getLink() + " - " + selectCarrucel.getTextoImagen() +  " --]");
        if(lstCarrucel.get(i).getNombre() == selectCarrucel.getNombre()){
            lstCarrucel.get(i).setNombre(selectCarrucel.getNombre());
            lstCarrucel.get(i).setTextoImagen(selectCarrucel.getTextoImagen());
            lstCarrucel.get(i).setLink(selectCarrucel.getLink());

        }
    }

 }
}
```

this is the metod for edit my item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating the content of the dialog at the time the whole page is renedered. Thus, `#{carrucelController.selectCarrucel}` is `null`, when the dialogs content is prepared.

Your button now sets the property in the backing bean - and just shows the dialog which was rendered at the time the property was null.

using `dynamic=true` on the dialog should solve your issue. This will render the content of the dialog the moment it is displayed (i.e. once the `setPropertyActionListener` calls `show()` through `onComplete`), rather than when the dialog is generated in the dom during first page load.

For reference: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/dynamic.xhtml